# how to convert milliseconds to minutes and milliseconds format

Tags: javascript

i'm receiving an audio track progress in milliseconds and need to convert it to minutes and milliseconds format M:MS, the format i'm aiming to achieve is similar to what we see in media player classic high precision option
[image]

i know the regular equation to format milliseconds to minutes and seconds which is like this:

```
        var minutes = Math.floor(millis / 60000);
        var seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
        return minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
```

but i don't know how to achieve the format i'm looking for. how can i do that? also how can i achieve the opposite?

Comment: The format in the image is minutes:seconds, not minutes:milliseconds. The dot is a decimal dot. It's 10.785 seconds and 5.477 seconds. The problem in your code is `.toFixed(0)`. It removes the decimal part of the seconds. VTC as typo.

Comment: Also voted to close as a typo. `toFixed(0)` should be `toFixed(3)` if you want to include three decimal places

Answer (score 0):

For instance:

*3.5 minutes == 210000ms*

```js
new Date(210000).toISOString().slice(14, -1) //03:30.000
```

or for tracks longer than an hour:

*78 minutes == 4.68e+6ms*

```js
new Date(4.68e+6).toISOString().slice(12, -1) //1:18:00.000"
```

Is that what you were going for?